# CPU usage goes up while computer enters into screensaver/screen goes dark

Tags: windows-7, power, thinkpad, cpu-usage

Computer/Laptop: **Lenovo T500**

When I leave my PC, it turns off the display after X minutes. That's fine.
However, since I use "Proccess Explorer" (SysInternals) there is a bit of a history in my tray about the CPU usage. The usage goes *UP*. (I also notice the fan gets louder when I leave my PC there for some reason, like a download / rip radios, whatever.)

Why is that?
(I'm using the hybrid ATI+Intel drivers by Lenovo. Latest at the moment.)

Comment: @Surfasb - Thanks, I'll do that. Will report back in a few minutes.

Comment: Aside from KCotreaus good idea, which helped a lot (defrag and update-tasks), I found that my windows would run the search-indexer every now and then and that this was a reason too for repetetive load-spikes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your computer is possibly running Scheduled Tasks that are set work when the system is idle, for example, defragging in the background.

Note the "Start this task only if the computer is idle for" parameter in the screenshot.

[image]

In the Task Scheduler, I would also try clicking on the "Display all running tasks" in the right pane. I am not sure if one of these idle tasks will show there, but it might.

Answer (score 1):

It could be many things.  Best bet is to upload the Process Explorer logs.

Another area you could look at is using Performance Monitor.  Under the Process category, you can add a "CPU usages" counter. It will list all the processes and their CPU usage, tracking them on a line graph with a sampling rate per sec.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problems.
The issue raises with the Logitech Setpoint drivers.

So here is what I did:

Use the 6.52 release of setpoint.

The culprit is actually Macros\MacroCore.dll. Replacing this file from the 6.61 version with the file from version 6.52 fixes the high cpu usage problem.

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly my problem too, using StPoint 6.61. I could hit Win+L to lock the screen and the CPU would spike until I logged in again. Just tried upgrading instead, to 6.67.83 (64bit) and it seems to be fixed.